# Visual Studio overload resolution trace

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Setting MSBuild verbosity to "Diagnostic" in Visual Studio earned me a simple `error C2661: 'catW2Mx': no overloaded function takes 2 arguments`. No better in all files in build directory.

Is there no way to make the Studio share more intimate details about its struggles with overload resolution ?

Comment: Another tool that can help you: press F12 over the call expression to see what overloads are considered.

Comment: In VS2019 F12 jumps to the definition of the function (same as Go to def.).

Comment: Exactly. That's my point.

Comment: I'm talking about log of the overload resolution process.

Comment: I know. I said another tool. With this you can see what overloads are considered.

Comment: At present, VS does not have the function you mentioned. If conditions permit, I suggest you use template instead of overloading.